# Como alterar is_staff quando clico no href?

Tags: python, django

Tenho uma tabela com os usuários no HTML com o id e o nome, por default quando cadastro uma pessoa ela vem com o is_staff=False.

Quero que quando eu clicar no link de Autorizar mude para is_staff=True, como faço isso na view?

```
 {% block content %}

         <p>Usuários</p>
        <table class="striped" id="cadastrados">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Código</th>
              <th>Nome</th>
              <th>Telefone</th>
              <th>Ramal</th>
              <th>É staff?</th>
              <th>Autorizar</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>

          {% for item in lista_usuarios %}
             <tr>
              <td>{{ item.id }}</td>

                <td>{{ item.first_name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ item.telefone }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.ramal }}</td>
                  <td> {{ item.is_staff }} </td>
                  <td> <a href="{% url 'cadastro:autorizar' %}"></a>  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
                        <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i></a> </td>
             </tr>
          {% endfor %}
       </tbody>
        </table>



        {% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
def quantities(request, value=None):
    if value == "2":

        usuarios = Perfil.objects.filter(is_staff=False)
        context = {'lista_usuarios': usuarios}
    else:
        usuarios = Perfil.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
        context = {'lista_usuarios': usuarios}

    return render(request, 'quantities.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa view que você postou é referente a url (cadastro:autorizar)? Parece que não. Então vou mostrar como seria uma view do zero.

O primeiro passo é prepara a sua url para receber um parametro (que será o id do usuario que você pretende "autorizar"). Então no seu urls.py vamos adicionar:

```
url(r'^cadastro/autorizar/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)$', 'views.funcao_autorizar', name='autorizar')
```

Agora no seu arquivo de urls tem uma url que espera por exemplo: 'cadastro/autorizar/5' e isso teoricamente vai autorizar o usuário de numero 5.

A forma de passar na url do django fica:

`<a href="{% url 'cadastro:autorizar' user_id=item.id %}">`

E sua view fica:

```
def funcao_autorizar(request, user_id):

  try:
      usuario = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
  except Exception as e:
      # retorna erro para o usuario

  usuario.is_staff = True
  usuario.save()
  # retorna para a pagina de sequinte
```

Comment: Obrigada, bem prático o meio que me mostrou, quando inspeciono a página cada botão de autorizar está pegando o id certinho, porém quando clico nada acontece

Comment: Bem tem varias formas de testar e identificar o erro. Uma delas (e a mais simples) seria colocar a url no navegador: localhost:8000/cadastro/atualizar/5 (caso você esteja em um ambiente local) e veja o erro que ele vai retornar. Lembre de ficar de olho no console do django.

Comment: Quando eu acesso pela url ele retorna o nome da pessoa, ou seja está pegando, certo? só o link href que não está funcionando mesmo

Comment: Quando você clica no link aparece o que? a url da pagina muda? Pode ser útil abrir outra perguntar e postar um print.

Comment: Nada acontece, como não tivesse link

Comment: parece um erro simples no href

Comment: Consegui, era o <a> fechando no lugar errado, ficou assim: <a href="{% url 'cadastro:autorizar' item.id %}" class="btn-floating btn-large red">
                        <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                        </a>